# Write consistency in body of ElasticSearch bulk request with NEST

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am wondering if it is possible to set the write consistency of all of the documents, or on a per document basis, within the body of a bulk request (either with NEST or ES JSON)? My code is currently using:

bulkDescriptor.Consistency(Consistency.All);

This generates a JSON request that sets the write consistency with an argument in the URI. The problem is my host is stripping off the query string at the end of the URI, so the write consistency setting is removed. I need a way to set the write consistency through the body of the JSON request.

Comment: The question is why "my host is stripping off the query string at the end of the URI" and how you can circumvent this.

Comment: I am using Amazon's implementation of ElasticSearch. An ES SME from Amazon told us this was the case.

From SME:
...note that we ignore all URL parameters for POST requests (they get stripped for request signing).
If you do want to set write_consistency.all, you will need to do it in the body of the POST.

Comment: Thank you Amazon! You're probably better off rolling up your own EC2 host and having a real ES instance. The stripped down AWS ES service won't let you do much more than babysitting your logs.

Comment: Yikes! Just for clarification, is it impossible to set the write consistency within the body of a bulk request?

Comment: @Ben what version of NEST are you using and version of Elasticsearch are you targeting?

Comment: @RussCam: I am using NEST 2.4.3 and targeting ES version 2.3.

Answer (score 0):

`consistency` can only be set on the query string; there is *no* body representation for consistency in Elasticsearch. [Here's the source for Elasticsearch 2.3](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/v2.3.0/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/rest/action/bulk/RestBulkAction.java#L82-L85):

```
String consistencyLevel = request.param("consistency");
if (consistencyLevel != null) {
    bulkRequest.consistencyLevel(WriteConsistencyLevel.fromString(consistencyLevel));
}
```